# Run every N lines from a different file within the file is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, file, exec

I have a big file that I`m running in python and I split it because it consumes too much ram... but, the result is 250 file of python code and I have too run it one at a time and is too much time consuming... I only want to execute 5 lines at a time from the big file without splitting it and using almost nothing of ram...

File:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
lines = 5
with open('finito.py') as bigfile:
# Execute every 5 lines??
```

Example Finito_file:

```
url = 'https://result.com/'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'lxml')
c=soup.find_all('h2')[0:4]
print(c,file=open("links.txt", "a"))
```

From the big file, every 5 line is like this...

Example Output:

```
[]
[<h2 class="tile--hero__headline"><span style="overflow:hidden;display:block"><span>Home For the Holidays</span></span></h2>, <h2 class="tile--hero__headline"><span style="overflow:hidden;display:block"><span>Disney+ Original Special</span></span></h2>, <h2 class="tile--hero__headline"><span style="overflow:hidden;display:block"><span>The Great Christmas Light Fight</span></span></h2>, <h2 class="tile--hero__headline"><span style="overflow:hidden;display:block"><span>Big Sky</span></span></h2>]
```

This is the result of each 5 lines of code from the finito.py... all the result will be save in links.txt

Comment: You could try writing a function

Answer (score 0):

Use `readline()` to read a file line by line without storing the entire file in memory.

```
def nextFive(file):
    lines = []
    for line in range(5):
        line = file.readline()
        if line:
            lines.append(line)
    return lines

bigFile = open('finito.py')
code = nextFive(bigFile)
while len(code) > 0:
    # Execute every 5 lines of code
    for line in code:
        exec line in globals(), locals()
    code = nextFive(bigFile)
bigFile.close()
```

Comment: THANK YOU Raymond Mutyaba! !  but, line 14, in <module>
    code = nextFive(bigFile)
NameError: name 'bigFile' is not defined

Comment: I did not capitalize the f in bigfile when I defined it. I just edited my answer to correct the error.

Comment: Thank you again Raymond!, but I`m really sorry to bother you again... there is a bug problem every time I execute the program... When I debug it in Pycharm, it open bigFile = open('finito.py'), but it doesn't read anything and when it goes to  code = nextFive(bigFile) and def... it return False and close the program because it didn`t find anything in the file... I`m trying to fixed but I don`t see how??

Comment: I edited my code to fix some bugs. Also, `exec line` will not run if there are errors in the code in 'finito.py'. In your example finito file `print(c,file=open("links.txt", "a"))` will cause an error because you cannot set `file = open("links.txt", "a")` inside `print()`.

Comment: Raymond Mutyaba, Thank You very much ! ! !... I really appreciated.... I would like to put the feedback to infinite plus to you, but my reputation is less then 15... the code works perfectly well... the way it works for me is exec(line) instead of exec line in globals(), locals().... Thank You very much ! ! !